# C# documetation add information about Attributes

Tags: c#, doxygen, sandcastle, xml-documentation

I use XML docs in C# and generate help files with doxygen or sandcastle.
I was wondering if there is any chance to put the information about used Attributes in the docs.

Let's say I would like to inform the order of a [ProtoMember](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) that is used as an Attribute:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Person{

    /// <summary>  Gets or sets the Age of a person. </summary>
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Int32 Age {get; set;}

}
```

Comment: You probably would be best of, in doxygen, to define an INPUT_FILTER converting the `[ProtoContract]` and `[ProtoMember(1)]` into comment.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in using [docFx](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html). A very good alternative. This one shows also the Attribute for each Property, so it is readable.